# Why can I not have two clients connected to the server?

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

Client.Java

```
package connection;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client extends Connection {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader socketInput;
    private PrintWriter socketOutput;

    private int clientId;

    public Client(String address, int port) {
        super(address, port);
        clientId = super.getConnectionsTotal();
    }

    public void connect() {

        // responsible for opening the socket
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket(super.getSocketAddress(), super.getSocketPort());
            System.out.println("Socket connected...");

            socketInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())); // reading input
            socketOutput = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true); // sending responses
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException u) {
            System.out.println("IP address not found [" + u + "]");
            return;
        }
        catch (IOException i) {
            System.out.println("Unknown error has occured [" + i + "]");
            return;
        }
    }

    public String send(String content) {
        try {
            socketOutput.println(clientId);
            socketOutput.println(content);

            String serverResponse = socketInput.readLine();

            if (serverResponse.equals("bye"))
                return null;

            return serverResponse;
        }
        catch (IOException i) {
            System.out.println("Unknown error has occured [" + i + "]");
            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean disconnect() {
        // responsible for closing the sockets
        try {
            socketOutput.close();
            socketInput.close();
            clientSocket.close();

            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException i) {
            System.out.println("Unknown error has occured [" + i + "]");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Server.java

```
package connection;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

/*
 * THIS FILE IS THE SERVER TO TALK TO THE DB
 */

public class Server extends Connection {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private ServerSocket server;

    public Server(int socketPort) {
        super(socketPort);
    }

    public void connect() {
        // opening to the server
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(super.getSocketPort());
            System.out.println("Server started...");

            while (true) {
                clientSocket = server.accept();

                System.out.println("A client has connected...");

                ClientHandler client = new ClientHandler(clientSocket);
                client.start();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException i) {
            System.out.println("Unknown error has occured [" + i + "]");
            return;
        }
    }

    public boolean disconnect() {
        // responsible for closing the server
        try {
            server.close();

            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException i) {
            System.out.println("Unknown error has occured [" + i + "]");
            return false;
        }
    }
}


class ClientHandler extends Thread {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader socketInput;
    private PrintWriter socketOutput;

    public ClientHandler(Socket cSocket) {
        clientSocket = cSocket;
        start();
    }

    public void start() {
        // opening to the server
        try {
            socketInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            socketOutput = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

            // sending back to client
            while (true) {
                try {
                    int connection = Integer.parseInt(socketInput.readLine());
                    String content = socketInput.readLine();

                    System.out.println("client " + connection + ": " + content);
                    
                    if (content.equals("quit")) {
                        socketOutput.println("end");
                        disconnect();
                        break;
                    }

                    socketOutput.println(content);
                }
                catch(IOException i) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }

        }
        catch(IOException i) {
            System.out.println("Unknown error has occured [" + i + "]");
            return;
        }
    }

    public boolean disconnect() {
        // responsible for closing the server
        try {
            socketOutput.close();
            socketInput.close();
            clientSocket.close();

            return true;
        }
        catch (IOException i) {
            System.out.println("Unknown error has occured [" + i + "]");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Connection.java

```
package connection;

public class Connection {
    static int connections = 0;

    private String socketAddress;
    private int socketPort;

    public Connection(int port) {
        socketPort = port;
    }
    
    public Connection(String address, int port) {
        socketAddress = address;
        socketPort = port;

        connections++;
    }

    public int getConnectionsTotal() {
        return connections;
    }

    public String getSocketAddress() {
        return socketAddress;
    }

    public int getSocketPort() {
        return socketPort;
    }
}
```

And I was using this to test the code:

Driver.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import connection.Client;
import connection.Server;

/*
 * THIS FILE IS JUST TO TES THE CLIENT AND SERVER
 */

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        String socketAddress = "127.0.0.1";
        int socketPort = 6666;

        System.out.println("*** Welcome to connection driver ***");

        System.out.print("s(erver) / c(lient): ");
        String input = scnr.nextLine();

        // client
        if (input.equals("s")) {
            Server server = new Server(socketPort);
            server.connect();

            if (server.disconnect())
                System.out.println("Server closed...");
            else
                System.out.println("Served closing error..."); 
        }

        // server
        else if (input.equals("c")) {
            String content, serverResponse;

            Client client = new Client(socketAddress, socketPort);

            if (client.getConnectionsTotal() <= 2) {
                client.connect();

                while (true) {
                    System.out.print("> ");
                    content = scnr.nextLine();

                    serverResponse = client.send(content);
                    if (serverResponse == null) {
                        System.out.println("Goodbye...");

                        if (client.disconnect())
                            break;
                    }

                    System.out.println("server says: " + serverResponse);

                }
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Too many connections...");
        }

        scnr.close();
    }
}
```

When I run the server and then the client, only one client can communicate with the server. Why won't the server communicate with the second client until the one first disconnects?

Comment: do not Override `start` from `Thread` (e.g. in `ClientHandler`) - you are *taking away* its functionality (of starting a thread)  || also note that `start()` is being called twice (constructor and in `connect()` - both times no additional thread will be started

Comment: I changed the function's name to connect() so there is no overlap. Do I have to call start() (for thread) and connect (for the method)?

Comment: @ArfurNarf He is not choosing a client IP address or port number. Your comment is irrelevant.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'only one client can communicate'? What happens instead? Where are you handling the case where `readLine()` returns null?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure, if you have more than one client, that each client is different (i.e. if you try to connect more than once to a server, from clients with the same address and port, that's not gonna work).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to make each client different? Thanks!

Comment: As I said, each client should have a different address and/or port. Right now all your instances of Client connect from localhost using port 6666, as per your Driver class.

Comment: Hmm. I thought the client and server must share a port. Does this mean two clients cannot connect to a single server?

Comment: No, of course not. But you'll agree with me that if you connect from the same address using the same port, that's the same connection, right? Just connect from different addresses if you must keep the port constant (though a server could conceivably listen on more than one port).

Comment: He is calling `new Socket(super.getSocketAddress(), super.getSocketPort());`. There is nothing there that specifies a local port, or that violates any other condition stated in this answer.